# Samba file lock prevents media unmount

Tags: ubuntu, mount, server-message-block, unmount

I have a small server with a samba share that sometimes I use to share removable disks connected in the hot swap bays.
After mounting a disk and accessing it, I try to unmount it, but umount refuses (even using `-f`) to do it because the disk is busy: `umount: /share/external: target is busy.`.

`lsof` reports:

```
smbd      62850                                root  cwd       DIR               8,65       4096          1 /share/external
smbd      62850                                root   46r      DIR               8,65       4096          1 /share/external
smbd      62851                          alessandro  cwd       DIR               8,65       4096          1 /share/external
```

`smbstatus` shows the mountpoint is locked (I already closed the file manager):

```
Locked files:
Pid          User(ID)   DenyMode   Access      R/W        Oplock           SharePath   Name   Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
62850        1000       DENY_NONE  0x81        RDONLY     NONE             /share/external   .   Mon Mar 14 17:09:58 2022
```

So, to unmount the drive I have to restart smbd first and then I can run umount successfully, but I want to avoid restarting the service, or killing processes manually (as I saw searching online).
I also tried to disable possible locks in smb.conf with

```
        locking = No
        oplocks = No
```

but without success.

Does someone know how to stop this behavior and allow unmounting without restarting?

###### Useful information:

- Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-104-generic x86_64)
- Samba version 4.13.17-Ubuntu

Comment: have you tried `smbclose /share/external` ?

Comment: @djdomi just done but no luck `smbclose: command not found`
I tried googling the command but found nothing.

Comment: i use apt-file if a command is not working

Comment: @djdomi I tried `apt-file search smbclose` and `apt-file list smbclose` but still nothing, are you sure smbclose is included in samba from repository and is not from a custom compiled version of it?

Comment: well the other way would to kill the PID.

Comment: Could you explain what is `smbclose` for a program?